# image repeats on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how can i prevent my image to repeat on click. every time i click on the image the same image appears again how can i prevent this from happening. im using draggable and resizable maybe thats why this is happening here is a quick code

```js
<script>// External added
    jQuery(download).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper").hide();
        jQuery(".out-put-img1").hide();
        jQuery("#imajes45").change(function () {
            var selected = jQuery('#imajes45').val();
            if (selected == "new-upload") {
                jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper").show();
            } else {
                jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper").hide();
            }
        });

        //File
        function readURL(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    jQuery(".out-put-img1").show();
                    $('#output1').attr('src', e.target.result);
//                   / $('.append-img').append('src', e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        jQuery("#upload-img1").change(function () {
            readURL(this);
   
 $(".samson").draggable();
$(".out-put-img1").resizable();
 

        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    // External added
    jQuery(download).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper1").hide();
        jQuery(".out-put-img2").hide();
        jQuery("#imajes45").change(function () {
            var selected = jQuery('#imajes45').val();
            if (selected == "new-upload") {
                jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper1").show();
            } else {
                jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper1").hide();
            }
        });

        //File
        function readURL(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    jQuery(".out-put-img2").show();
                    $('#output2').attr('src', e.target.result);
//                   / $('.append-img').append('src', e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        jQuery("#upload-img2").change(function () {
            readURL(this);
   
  $(".dragbal1").draggable();
$(".out-put-img2").resizable();
  
  
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    // External added
    jQuery(download).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper2").hide();
        jQuery(".out-put-img4").hide();
        jQuery("#imajes45").change(function () {
            var selected = jQuery('#imajes45').val();
            if (selected == "new-upload") {
                jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper2").show();
            } else {
                jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper2").hide();
            }
        });

        //File
        function readURL(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    jQuery(".out-put-img4").show();
                    $('#output4').attr('src', e.target.result);
//                   / $('.append-img').append('src', e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        jQuery("#upload-img4").change(function () {
            readURL(this);
   
 $(".chinass2").draggable();
$(".out-put-img4").resizable();
  

        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<div id="snake" class="samson">
<img id="output1" class="out-put-img1" style="position: absolute;top: 108px;right: 108px" height="80px" width="80px"></div>
<div id="lizard" class="dragbal1">
 <img id="output2" class="out-put-img2" style="position: absolute;top: 108px;right: 108px" height="80px" width="80px"></div>
<div id="rat" class="chinass2">
 <img id="output4" class="out-put-img4" style="position: absolute;top: 108px;right: 108px" height="80px" width="80px"></div>
```

Comment: Can you edit your post so that the code works and we can replicate the issue?

Comment: what about if i give you a website so you can see for your self?

Comment: the duplicates only happen on uploaded files https://torcdesign.com/mars/

Comment: That's not the preferred way of making a post http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It helps if you only provide the code that is relevant to reproduce the problem so we don't have to go hunting and sifting around, and providing a code sample is always better than linking to something 3rd party because people use SO for help and the 3rd party sites and code will change over time.

Comment: im really sorry here is a fiddle but it does not work it contains the same code that im working on but i cant make it work on fiddle i hope this helps if not then im really sorry for wasting you time https://jsfiddle.net/kk5r1p2b/19/